# Config files shared between projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm starting a new web based project that we may be distributing for people to install themselves.

Usually I put DB credentials in the webconfig/static class. However, this time I'm going to be setting up a shared project which houses the datalayer, so it could be a web form, win form etc all hitting it.

What's the best way for me to do the DB connections so the Datalayer has the credentials in it rather than whatever project accesses it. But with the kicker that the people who have installed the app can change?

Comment: If you are sharing an access data layer project among various projects why would you let people who installed the application change this? wouldn't that affect the other people? I am a bit confused by your question/solution

Comment: Sorry, I don't want them to change anything but put in the database connection details

Comment: You can have a single project manage all the data access operations, this is very common. Usually this type of project has all the database connection string information in a configuration file just like any individual project.